# How to get to the ascii code of a character in a string MASM Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, character, ascii, masm

Say I have a string named abc initialized as "something". To get the first character of this string I would do abc[0] which would show 's'. Is there some notation that I could use to get the ascii code for 's' which is 73h? I'm using MASM.

I'm trying to subtract the ascii code from a character to form a different character. So if 's' is 115d, I want to subtract 4 so it's 111d so then it becomes the letter 'o'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the ASCII string `"something"` and you read the first byte from that string you'll get `115`, which also equals `'s'`, which also equals `73h`. There's no conversion necessary because it's just a byte with some value. Whether you want to view that value as `115`, `'s'` or `73h` doesn't really become relevant until you want to print it.

```
.data
something db "something",0

.code
mov al,[something]    ; al = 115 / 73h / 's'
sub al,4              ; al = 111 / 6Fh / 'o'
```